# Viewing the contents of a flatpak

Tags: package-management, packaging, flatpak

When I install a package, I like to see what it's installed. With apt I can use `apt-file show`, with AppImages I can view the mounted filesystem, and with Snap I could mount the snap without running it to see the contents.

How do I do the equivalent with a flatpak? Preferably, *before* running it?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is what you want.

Since Flatpak packages are installed to `/var/lib/flatpak/app` or `~/.local/share/flatpak/app`, you can view content of them in those folders.